# long time to open Ubuntu 20.04 Software Center

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 20.04

taking long time to open Ubuntu 20.04 software center, even when open taking too much time to install software
Is this happening to everyone  ????

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! A "long time" is a relative term and speed is dependent on a number of factors. What [flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077533/linux-flavors-and-versions) of Ubuntu 20.04 are you running? What are your hardware specifications? Please [edit] this info into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Download: 8.33 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..
Upload: 4.78 Mbit/s

Answer (score 0):

Run `speedtest-cli` from the terminal to test your internet bandwidth. If your speed test is OK, then your server mirror is too slow.

Comment: Download: 8.33 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed.
Upload: 4.78 Mbit/s

Comment: Internet bandwidth is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble loading the catagories of software. It worked once I shut off live patch. Is this your issue maybe?